# Running excel interop object on windows docker

Tags: c#, docker-compose, excel-interop

I migrated my console application(that implements excel manipulation of the iterop object) to a docker compose in order run on docker container of windows docker.
when reaching to this code part:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp  = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

getting this error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

any idea how to solve it?

Y.D

Comment: you'll have to install excel as well in that docker container

Comment: running into the exact same issue, is there a solution for this? I tried installing office inside the container, but I dont see the interop library ddl files inside c:\windows\assemblies\gac_msil